# CANNOT change file attribute as an admin in w7

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying this tutorial:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12183/how-to-run-xp-mode-in-virtualbox-on-windows-7/

but for some reason I get the access denied error while trying to change the file attribute of the .vhd file. I'm logged on as admin. what do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that you're not the owner of a file.
If you admin you can change the ownership first and then change the attribute.

Comment: thanks to you I've learned that there's something called file ownership. I successfully changed the file attribute